# Python Inheritance - Instance Has No Attribute

Tags: python, class, inheritance, attributes, instance

I'm new to python and just trying to test the syntax and get to know it.
The code below works fine except for when I get to inheritance. The final command "toString" function is not working and I can't for the life of me figure out why.

I'm sure I'm not doing something the most efficient way, but even if there's a more efficient way I'd first like to understand why what I'm doing is wrong.  thanks a lot. Please let me know if I need to clarify anything

```
#!/bin/python

class Animal:


        __name = ""
        __height = 0
        __weight = 0
        __sound = 0

        def __init__(self, name, height, weight, sound):
                self.__name = name
                self.__height = height
                self.__weight = weight
                self.__sound = sound

        def set_name(self,name):
                self.__name = name

        def get_name(self):
                return self.__name


        def set_height(self,height):
                self.__height = height

        def get_height(self):
                return self.__heiight

        def set_weight(self,weight):
                self.__weight=weight

        def get_weight(self):
                return self.__weight

        def set_sound(self,sound):
                self.__sound = sound

        def get_sound(self):
                return self.__sound

        def get_type(self):
                print("Animal")

        def toString(self):
                return("{} is {} inches tall, {} lbs, and says {}".format(self.__name, self.__height,self.__weight,self.__sound))



objCat = Animal('Whiskers', 33, 10, 'Meow')
print (objCat.toString())


# Attempt Inheritance

class cDog(Animal):

        __owner=""

        def __init__(self,name,height,weight,sound,owner):
                self.__owner=owner
                Animal.__init__(self,name,height,weight,sound)

        def __str__(self):
                return ("{}".format(self.__height))

        def set_owner(self,owner):
                self.__owner=owner

        def get_owner(self):
                return self.__owner

        def get_type(self):
                print("Dog")

        def toString(self):
                return ("{} is {} inches tall, {} lbs, says {}, and is owned by, {}".format(self.__name,self.__height,self.__weight,self.__sound,self.__owner))


objDog = cDog('Brewsky', 20, 75, 'Ruff', 'Jared')
print (objDog.toString())
```

Comment: JFYI This sample code is from Derek Banas' [Python Tutorial](https://youtu.be/N4mEzFDjqtA?t=2056). For those interested in learning Python or getting the full context.

Answer (score 2):

In your `Animal` class, the double underscore before the name of the attributes has made them (sort of) private.

Just delete the double underscore (or change it to one underscore, if you want to keep a weak indicator) and it will be fixed.
See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1301346/the-meaning-of-a-single-and-a-double-underscore-before-an-object-name-in-python) question for more information.